# How can I run netsh using batchfile?

Tags: batch-file, netsh

I am writing batch file to use 'netsh' command repetitive. So far I wrote this code.

```
@Echo Off
SET PCNAME=%COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN% 

@Echo On
netsh http add urlacl url=http://%COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN%:1000/ user=everyone

Exit
```

When I am running this command, this runs infinitely. Even when I run only

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://%COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN%:1000/ user=everyone
```

It's going infinitely.

What can I do to run it properly?

Comment: What is the name of your batch file? Is it `netsh.cmd` or `netsh.bat`?

Comment: filename was netsh.bat. I changed file name and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filename was netsh.bat. I changed file name and its working fine